Can paper_trail track changes to derived/calculated values?
I'm somewhat familiar with the paper_trail gem, but wanted to ask a question about if/how/should I use it for tracking derived values, and not just changes to the database columns.
I'm working on a system that already has an existing column-level audit of all changes that we care about, so I don't need a security audit solution. What I want to add is tracking of changes from derived/calculated values (i.e. those defined by business rules or code), in addition to the existing audit changes.
A simple example would be the following:

A customer buys a product
This is their 10th purchase, and as a result they've earned a reward
While I do store all customers' orders, and I could update a count of the orders on the customer's database record, which I could then use to trigger paper_trail, the problem is that only some customers, based on some business rules elsewhere in the system that could change at any time, and not all customers are eligible for the reward from point #2.

The fact that only some customers are eligible for an award, when this situation happens I want to record that fact somewhere. Would paper_trail be a good fit for this kind of derived/conditional event tracking via its custom event tracking, or would you roll your own solution for tracking events? It seems like paper_trail could be utilized to track this, but mixing auditing data (which paper_trail seems to have been originally built for) with customer lifecycle events, seems like a misuse of paper_trail ... and yet paper_trail ultimately creates a time series trail of what happened, which is useful for me in terms of using that time series data for things like the triggering of sending the relevant customers the rewards. For example, I see this answer talk about using paper_trail to track that a notification was sent.
So, with this derived change tracking, I'm thinking something along these lines, and I don't know if paper_trail is a good fit:

Some event happens  ->  This event might match     ->  I'd like to make a
- database change       something I want to track      record saying the customer
- customer purchase     in some configurable           has earned a reward
- any other event       customer rewards system.


Is paper_trail a good fit for something like this, or is it better to keep this separate and not mix auditing and event data together (is there really a difference between the two, other than the fact that they are two different categories of events/changes a system might care about)?

Seems like a users reciept of a reward and the condition (possibly role) associated with eligibility should both be available from a database perspective, no? In other words if the eligibility and subsequent receipt of an award are both solely in memory business logic how do you later validate this?

Yes, you could use paper trail, but not sure what it buys you except for complication.

@engineersmnky - yes, I think the result of using paper_trail would be to record the award eligibility being triggered. The business logic would live in code, but I would want the database to store the fact that an award was triggered in the database to feed other things, such as actually issuing the award, or sending an email about the award, etc.

@dbugger - "... but not sure what it buys you except for complication."
This was my general sentiment as well, but if I do something specific for this use case I wanted to bounce that idea off of some folks before reinventing the wheel. As of me writing this comment, I'm leaning towards a specialized solution as well. We'll see.
